# I cannot Write or move any apps to my SD card

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, root-access, external-sd

I bought a 16GB SD card for my cheap android phone a few days ago and have been trying everything to get apps onto it with no success.
The phone is model is a ZTE Fit 4G running KitKat 4.4.4, and yes, I have already rooted the device to allow write access to SD card with kingroot. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have just rooted, or rooted and enabled write access afterwards? Rooting alone doesn't do that. If you missed the latter part: [this list](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_storagemedia#group_535) has a few apps doing it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The default install location can be changed using the adb shell pm command. The command is: `adb shell pm set-install-location 2`. The three options for set-install-location are 0 (auto), 1 (internal), and 2 (external). This can cause applications to break or other behavior that is undesirable. You can view this information by typing `adb shell pm` at the terminal. Side note: you can check what the current default install location is by typing `adb shell pm get-install-location`.